# In PostgreSQL how to combine NOT IN and LIKE?

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, notin

How do you combine `NOT IN` and `LIKE`?

Let's assume we have a table that contains a column of names (something like 'blue cheese', 'gouda cheese' and so on) and I want to select all the names that doesn't contain 'cheese', 'milk', 'meat'.

As far as I understand to look for something that is not in an array of strings you use `NOT IN` and the pass the strings

```
SELECT names FROM some_table NOT IN('cheese','milk','meat');
```

but how do I pass

```
LIKE '%cheese%'
```

to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construct `LIKE ANY (ARRAY[...])` appears to meet your needs;

```
craig=> SELECT a FROM (
           VALUES ('cheesy'), ('imilk'), ('donut'), ('pie'), ('avocado'), ('meaty')
        ) x(a) 
        WHERE NOT a LIKE ANY (ARRAY['%cheese%','%milk%','%meat%']);

    a    
---------
 cheesy
 donut
 pie
 avocado
(4 rows)
```

You need the wildcard characters if you want to use `LIKE` this way. If you really just want equality, you can use:

```
NOT = ANY (...)
```

Comment: @boo_boo_bear: Or `WHERE a !~~ ALL (...)` / `WHERE a <> ALL (...)` if there are no `NULL` values involved.

Comment: Why `where  "ID" not like any ( array['RC11909%','RC11917%','RC14755%','RC14990%'])` doesn't work but `where not "ID" like any ( array['RC11909%','RC11917%','RC14755%','RC14990%'])`  works as expected?