# SQL: do we need ANY/SOME and ALL keywords?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, ansi-sql

I'm using SQL (SQL Server, PostgreSQL) over 10 years and still I'm never used `ANY/SOME` and `ALL` keywords in my production code. All situation I've encountered I could get away with `IN`, `MAX`, `MIN`, `EXISTS`, and I think it's more readable.

For example:

```
-- = ANY
select * from Users as U where U.ID = ANY(select P.User_ID from Payments as P);

-- IN
select * from Users as U where U.ID IN (select P.User_ID from Payments as P);
```

Or

```
-- < ANY
select * from Users as U where U.Salary < ANY(select P.Amount from Payments as P);

-- EXISTS
select * from Users as U where EXISTS (select * from Payments as P where P.Amount > U.Salary);
```

Using `ANY/SOME` and `ALL`:

- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)
- [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx)
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)
- [SQL FIDDLE with some examples](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bfc43/12)

So the question is: am I missing something? is there some situation where `ANY/SOME` and `ALL` shine over other solutions?

Comment: I haven't used them either in the past 13 years.

Comment: I never used `EXCEPT` either. I stick to `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: I couldn't agree with that, I think `EXCEPT` is useful to find differences between two tables with same schema

Comment: But tables with the same structure (within the same schema) are rare. Could be different when you allow views or table expressions, though.

Comment: In Postgres, the ANY/ALL syntax is useful for searching ARRAYs, though I've never used it in vanilla SQL.
[Array searching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING)

Comment: @RomanPekar, `= ANY` and `IN` are alias for subqueries. So your first comparison doesn't make much sense actually, it's comparing the same thing with itself.

Comment: @Pacerier well it's not the point of the question, question is is `any`, `some` and `all` could be easily removed from the code

Comment: @joop Actually, I find that `EXCEPT` is an easy way to compare the results of two `SELECT` statements: `SELECT … EXCEPT SELECT …` would yield an empty set of the results are the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find ANY and ALL to be very useful when you're not just testing equality or inequality. Consider

```
'blah' LIKE ANY (ARRAY['%lah', '%fah', '%dah']);
```

[as used my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16854442/398670).

`ANY`, `ALL` and their negations can greatly simplify code that'd otherwise require non-trivial subqueries or CTEs, and they're significantly under-used in my view.

Consider that `ANY` will work with any operator. It's very handy with `LIKE` and `~`, but will work with tsquery, array membership tests, hstore key tests, and more.

```
'a => 1, e => 2'::hstore ? ANY (ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

or:

```
'a => 1, b => 2'::hstore ? ALL (ARRAY['a', 'b'])
```

Without `ANY` or `ALL` you'd probably have to express those as a subquery or CTE over a `VALUES` list with an aggregate to produce a single result. Sure, you can do that if you want, but I'll stick to `ANY`.

There's one real caveat here: On older Pg versions, if you're writing `ANY( SELECT ... )`, you're almost certainly going to be better off in performance terms with `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...)`. If you're on a version where the optimizer will turn `ANY (...)` into a join then you don't need to worry. If in doubt, check `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: +1, but what RDBMS are you using? I've tried to put your query into work in PostgreSQL and best I could get is `like any (values ('%lah'), ('%fah'), ('%dah'));`
[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ac24b/9)

Comment: It needs to be `ANY(ARRAY[...])`.  But yes, this is generally quite useful.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut Whoops, good point. I keep on thinking it takes the same simple literal-list syntax as `IN (...)`

Comment: Interesting - could you add somemore examples or links which illustrate your second point, please?

Comment: In cases where ANY/ALL mean MAX/MIN  what advantages have one option over the other?

Comment: @skan That doesn't make sense. `min` and `max` are aggregates. `any` and `all` are completely different.

Answer (score 6):

No, I've never used the `ANY`, `ALL`, or `SOME` keywords either, and I've never seen them used in other people's code.  I assume these are vestigal syntax, like the various optional keywords that appear in some places in SQL (for example, `AS`).

Keep in mind that SQL was defined by a committee.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried anything but no missing anything, just different type of habit only if i use a `Not` condition. the exists and in will need to add not while any/some just change the operator to `<>`. i only use sql server and i not sure about the other software might missing something