# SQL is IN made redundany by ANY operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is the IN operator made redundant by the ANY operator? I've learned that IN and = ANY do the same thing, but any can also be used with <, >, <>, etc. so my question is are there any actual use cases for IN where =ANY wouldn't be suitable?

Comment: I think they are equivalent.

Comment: These serve logically different functions, each has a specific use-case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: do we need ANY/SOME and ALL keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588074/sql-do-we-need-any-some-and-all-keywords) To be honest, most people find `ANY` and `ALL` highly confusing

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server at least they are not totally equivalent as ANY doesn't seem to accept a simple value list like IN can.

```
-- Works
SELECT 1 WHERE 'A' IN ('A','B')
-- Fails with Incorrect syntax near 'A'.  
SELECT 1 WHERE 'A' = ANY('A','B')
-- Works
SELECT 1 WHERE 'A'= ANY (SELECT 'A' UNION SELECT 'B')
```

Comment: … WHERE 'A' = any(SELECT 'A' UNION SELECT 'B')

Comment: @lptr Opps, your right of course, copied the wrong line from what I was testing.